# Which function encodes accentuated letters in PHP?

Tags: php

There is a MySQL database and I want to select columns from a table.

I must return a `String` from the `concatenation` of the selected column values. But in one of the columns there are `accentuated` letters in the column value , like `é`.

So how to encode the column returned value ?

**NB :** I already wrote `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of the PHP file.

Comment: Is this being returned in as HTML, or as something else (file attachment for example)?

Comment: The PHP file is to be a webservice , it contains functions that the webservice calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining charset with `SET NAMES 'utf-8'` may help.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 1):

What encoding is your database table in? On a lot of installations, MySQL defaults to `LATIN-1`. Make sure the table stores its data as UTF-8, then make sure that the connection between MySQL and PHP is in UTF-8. The easy way to do that is running the query `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting, but you can also set a default encoding.

Next, the UTF-8 header should be sent from the server to the browser, but you've already done that by adding the `header()` call.

If your database table is currently not encoded as UTF-8, you might need to re-enter your data after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Multibyte String Module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) can be of some help to you, part of the [Human Language and Character Encoding Support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.international.php).